# jquery click on nav button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple navigation that the user clicks on and its slides up and user clicks on it again and it slides down and closes. Currently I am using removeClass and addClass to change out the position of the nav open/close arrow. The problem I am having is the nav open/close arrow changes its position when you click to open the nav but when you click the arrow to close the nav, the arrow doesn't change back to it original position. If some could look at my code I would greatly appreciate it! I can't figure out why this isn't working. Thanks!

Here is a link to my code http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/QmEcs/6/

```
$(function(){
var $itemContent = $('.drop-down-nav');
$('.drop-down-btn').click(function(e){
  $('.drop-down-btn').removeClass('drop-down-btn');
  $('.drop-down-nav-container a').addClass('drop-down-btn-up');
  e.preventDefault();
  if($itemContent.hasClass('opened')){
    $itemContent.slideUp('fast').toggleClass('closed opened');
  } else {
    $itemContent.slideDown('fast').toggleClass('closed opened');
  }
});

$(function(){
var $itemContent = $('.drop-down-nav');
$('.drop-down-btn-up').click(function(e){
  $('.drop-down-btn-up').removeClass('drop-down-btn-up');
  $('.drop-down-nav-container a').addClass('drop-down-btn');
  e.preventDefault();
  if($itemContent.hasClass('opened')){
    $itemContent.slideUp('fast').toggleClass('closed opened');
  } else {
    $itemContent.slideDown('fast').toggleClass('closed opened');
  }
});
```

});

Comment: Where is the arrow you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to change the class from `opened` to `closed` in the second function.  Thus both functions are effectively trying to slide the element down--and neither of them up.

Comment: Thanks jegesh for the info and help!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QmEcs/7/

I couldn't see the arrow.

But the attached fiddle correctly sets the class on the drop down from black to red and back again.

```
$(function(){
var $itemContent = $('.drop-down-nav');
$('.drop-down-btn-up, .drop-down-btn').click(function(e){
  $('.drop-down-btn-up, .drop-down-btn').toggleClass('drop-down-btn-up drop-down-btn');
  e.preventDefault();
  if($itemContent.hasClass('opened')){
    $itemContent.slideUp('fast').toggleClass('closed opened');
  } else {
    $itemContent.slideDown('fast').toggleClass('closed opened');
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you SlitCanvas! I guess I had some unnecessary code. This works great! thanks so much for the help!